# Which answer should I accept - that which solved my problem or that which solved the question asked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, accepted-answer

Suppose I ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641231/python-working-around-memory-leaks/) and I receive one answer that answers the question that was asked really well and another answer that solved my problem without answering the question I asked. Which answer should I accept?

Comment: How was it able to solve your problem but not answer it?

Comment: I was asking about workarounds for when you can't find a memory leak, the answer told me how to find the memory leak. Read the link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would personally accept the answer which *actually* helped you the most - but upvote both, of course.

Bear in mind that the next person who finds your answer when asking about memory leaks will probably benefit more from the "stop the cause" than "treat the symptom" approach too, so it's good for *them* if that answer is at the top.